# ngChange is not picking up changes from the model

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I am trying to access the obj from the select in my controller but the only thing that I end up getting is null and undefined.

```
        <select
        ng-change="watchActions(part)" 
        ng-options="part.serial as part.description for part in rawBaList.items" 
        ng-model="currentChose"
        ></select>

             $scope.currentChose = null;

             $scope.watchActions = function (obj) {
                  console.log($scope.currentChose);
                  console.log(obj);
              };

                $scope.$watch('currentChose', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if(newValue){
                        console.log("here the new value goes");
                    }
                });
```

Here is the ex of data:

```
{
count: 2,
items: [
{serial: 2, description: 'here is some description'},
{serial: 24, description: 'some other description'}
]
}
```

Comment: could you reproduce the issue in plunkr?

Comment: Typo in question, or are you missing the ending quote for `ng-model="currentChose`?

Comment: I think we're missing something here. I've recreated what you've given here: http://embed.plnkr.co/SOdhdy2NVuCY4vT2O7pP/preview. $scope.$watch is working find (check the console).

Comment: thanks, I didnt mention it was a part of directive, and ngModel couldnt see the scope of controller, so the solution was to add $parent. currentChose

Answer (score 0):

it was a scope issue, $parent.currentChose fixed it